# differential equation :$ (x^2+1)y'-4xy=xe^{-x} $

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

How to solve this simple equation ?
$$
(x^2+1)y'-4xy=xe^{-x}
$$
In fact I can't find a particular solution for this equation, because i need to calculate the primitive of 
$$
\frac{e^{-x}}{1+x^2}
$$ 
I help please for this two question ?

Answer (score 2):

multiplying by $(x^2 + 1)^{-3},$ an integrating factor, gives us $$(x^2 + 1)^{-2}y'-4x(1+x^2)^{-3} = \left(\frac y{(1+x^2)^2}\right)' = \frac{xe^{-x}}{(1+x^2)^3} $$  on integration gives a particular solution in the form $$y =(1+x^2)^2\int_0^x\frac{te^{-t}}{(1+t^2)^3} \, dt $$

i am not sure if the integral can be evaluated in closed form.

Comment: the integral can't be evaluated ?

Comment: The integral can be evaluated, but it will involve non-elementary functions (typically some exponential integral).

Comment: Hello @abel, I sent you a message long ago, did you receive it? :-) Hope you're enjoying your time, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Notice, we have $$(x^2+1)\frac{dy}{dx}-4xy=xe^{-x}$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}-\frac{4x}{x^2+1}y=\frac{xe^{-x}}{x^2+1}$$
Above is the linear differential equation of form $\frac{dy}{dx}+yP(x)=Q(x)$ such that $P(x)=-\frac{4x}{x^2+1}$ & $Q(x)=-\frac{xe^{-x}}{x^2+1}$

integration factor $(I.F.)$ as follows $$I.F.=e^{\int \frac{-4x}{x^2+1}dx}=e^{-2\ln(x^2+1)}=\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}$$ Hence, the solution is given as 
$$y(I.F.)=\int (I.F.)\frac{xe^{-x}}{x^2+1} \ dx$$
$$y\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}=\int\frac{1}{(x^2+1)^2}\frac{xe^{-x}}{x^2+1} \ dx$$
$$y=(x^2+1)^2\int\frac{xe^{-x}}{(x^2+1)^3}\ dx$$

Above is the standard solution of linear D.E. You can evaluate above integral in closed form if possible.